# How to get Typescript to recognise generic commonalities between two of the same type of interface in a union?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a few types outlined as such:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}
interface Core<T> {
    fnc: (arg: T) => void;
    args: T;
}
interface One extends Core<Person> {
    type: 'modifyPerson';
}
interface Two extends Core<Person & { age: number }> {
    type: 'modifyAgeingPerson';
}
```

I then have a function which can handle both modifying a shared property of a person or an ageing person - as such it has a union type, an example would be as follows:

```
modifyPersonCharacteristics(person: One | Two) {
    person.fnc({ ...person.args, name: 'Steven' });
}
```

Typescript however doesn't like this due to the fact that there's type overlap - but in this case because of the use of a generic should it even matter? either an instance of a One or Two could both accept the arguments passed.

Is there a way to get typescript to look at the bigger picture of the generic?

A side note is that the following works, but for obvious reasons I'd rather not:

```
modifyPersonCharacteristics(person: One | Two) {
    if (person.type === 'modifyPerson') {
        person.fnc({ ...person.args, name: 'Steven' });
    } else {
        person.fnc({ ...person.args, name: 'Steven' });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are defining the parameter of `fnc` too narrowly.  To your point about the bigger picture--the point is that your `fnc` will work with any type that extends (or intersects) Person, so it just needs to be declared that way, as so

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}
interface Core<T> {
    fnc: (arg: Person) => void;  //This is the line that's changed.
    args: T;
}
interface One extends Core<Person> {
    type: 'modifyPerson';
}
interface Two extends Core<Person & { age: number }> {
    type: 'modifyAgeingPerson';
}

function modifyPersonCharacteristics(person: One | Two) {
    person.fnc({ ...person.args, name: 'Steven' });
}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxJxIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESQL7vGiSyIoAwligQAPABUAfPm6lkMEAloAKOFCa10UbCACUyALwyAblmAATFsQD0NiQAtgGZM%20RgHKADagUHuGAA5C4IDnAgTBAWAHRypOpMGLQSbKRcpLzQ8EjIAPIgKBAAHpAgFi7ComLaujKE8iRgAJ4ADjTIgRRYFsAwTTU4gamccpn8ORIA7ljIxaXlyJXiA7gAZPjIcJG0IACuFABG0MgcdXGNre2d3b1NAIKRzCtDcukkcjC7SmDAOMhdPT6K0EYSgiD4zh%20CAwKjaOhwtHyKAAPsgplgDPUGsg4bpoooECo8MhoqTcThogkMAAaZDkKi0QIAZUgJggIECJz0w2IHCAA).

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue of the generic, the function type is linked to the objects type, and the args generic type are equivalent to that type, in the situation where I would need to check for type === modifyAgeingPerson and then pass the func { ...person.args, age: 12 } then this fix wouldn't work.

Comment: In that case, would this work: `fnc: <U extends Person>(arg: U) => void;`

Comment: With this change it's typing the function differently to the object, which doesn't link the function type to the arg type which is the point of the generic